# How to include a variable in io:get_line (Erlang)

Tags: erlang

Is there a way to put a variable in a `io:get_line()` code? I tried

```
io:get_line("~s: ",[Variable]).
```

but it doesn't work. So my question is there another implementation for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the format string and arguments to `io_lib:format/2` first, and then send that to `io:get_line/1`:

```
1> Variable = "Name".
"Name"
2> io:get_line(io_lib:format("~s: ", [Variable])).
Name: Dogbert
"Dogbert\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fread/3](http://erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#fread-3) function:

> Reads characters from the standard input (IoDevice), prompting it with Prompt. Interprets the characters in accordance with Format. Format contains control sequences that directs the interpretation of the input.

Comment: Well, what I meant was that I'd like to put a variable inside the `io:get_line()` prompt. Like
    `io:get_line("~s: ",[Variable]).`
will translate to
    'Somevar: '